# What is the difference between void and self in a setter method

Tags: php

I am starting to use the doctrine ORM mapping system.

What is the difference between void and self in a setter function?

**Void**

```
/**
* @param string|null $firstname
*/
public function setFirstname(?string $firstname): void
{
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
}
```

and

**SELF**

```
/**
* @param string|null $firstname
*/
public function setFirstname(?string $firstname): self
{
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
    return $this
}
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this can be posted as answer

Comment: Just to state that explicitly: neither the question nor the answer are in any way confined to Doctrine Entities. `self`and `void` return type hints are a language feature of php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### void

`void` means that the method doesn't return anything. ([Added in PHP 7.1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.void-functions)). From the documentation:

> A void return type has been introduced. Functions declared with void as their return type must either omit their return statement altogether, or use an empty return statement. NULL is not a valid return value for a void function.

#### self

`self` means that the method returns the class instance (for method chaining etc). It means that you can use the class like this:

```
$class->setFirstname('Foo')->setLastname('Bar');
```

If you look at your two methods, you see that the one with `void` doesn't contain any `return`-statement, while the second one has `return $this`.

**Note:** Just as @simon.ro mentions in the comment under the original question:

> *Just to state that explicitly: neither the question nor the answer are in any way confined to Doctrine Entities. self and void return type hints are a language feature of php.*